# How to make the height of div same as width to create responsive squares when using grid system?

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm using Skeleton boilerplate to create my grid. The grid I'm trying to achieve consists of 3 squares per row. I have tried making the height percentage (33.33%) but it still doesn't create a square. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

On CSS3 you will use `vh` unit, this is same at percentage unit, is relative, in this case to `viewport height`.

`33.33%` as same to `33.33vh` and your box should adjust to `view height` of viewport.

View all [Css Units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

**example**

```css
.box{
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33vh;
  }
.foo{background-color: red;}
.bar{background-color: purple;}
.na{background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<div class='box foo'></div>
<div class='box bar'></div>
<div class='box na'></div>
```

These are Relative Unit on CSS.
**Try one of them.**

[image]